# POST request : Webapi receives empty content from angular client

Tags: post, asp.net-web-api, http-post

I'm trying to post an object to my API, but it can't be consumed there.

Client Code

```
const url = '/odata/StammVersicherter';
        const headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        const requestBody = JSON.stringify(data);
        return this._http.post(url, requestBody , { headers: headers }).map(
            res => {
                // do something with the response
            }
        );
```

Resulting Request
[image]

Api Code

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post([FromBody]Data data)
    {
      string content = await this.Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(); // empty! 
      if (!ModelState.IsValid)
      {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
      }
      _dataContext.Data.Add(data);

      await _dataContext.SaveChangesAsync();

      return Created(versicherter);
    }
```

When this call reaches my api method, the Data object is null. Any quick ideas?

Comment: I obviously wasn't paying all due attention. Deserialization started, but completed with errors. (A string that could not be converted to a number).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As my comment on the original question indicates: The JSON Serializer ran into errors which caused the content to be null

Answer (score 1):

As you are using POST request, then you should go with 
"content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",

**below is the reference code in javascript.**

```
var settings = {
  "async": true,
  "crossDomain": true,
  "url": "your URL HERE",
  "method": "POST",
  "processData": false,
  "contentType": false,
  "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
   "data": {
"username": "srussell@org.com.au.test",
"password": "test",
 }    }

$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
  console.log(response);
});
```

Comment: As I'm sending plain json and not a formdata object, this doesn't work either. It should be possible to send JSON without wrapping it in formData.

Answer (score 1):

Well in that case you could send data like below, but your json data key field should match with model in server side.

```
var settings = {
      "async": true,
      "crossDomain": true,
      "url": "Your URL",
      "method": "POST",
      "headers": {
        "content-type": "application/json",
        "cache-control": "no-cache",

      },
      "processData": false,
      "data": "{\"Name\":\"abc\",\"EMail\":\"abc@xyz.com\"}"
    }

    $.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
      console.log(response);
    });
```